# WP-CLI command to update all plugins and core fails when executed from cron

Tags: updates, wp-cli

I have the following WP-CLI command to update all plugins and core. It seems to fail when being executed from cron (other cron commands work):

```
0 0 * * 0 for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin update --all --allow-root; wp core update --allow-root; done
```

I tried to run it manually (did so after a manual update from GUI after a period without updates), I got the following for all sites:

```
Success: Plugin already updated.
Success: WordPress is up to date.
```

Why would the command fail on cron?

I tried to debug this by letting the command run each minute (`* * * * *`) and checking the output (cron output usually goes to `/var/mail/root`).

### /var/mail/root output:

```
Subject: Cron <root@machine_name> for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin update --all --allow-root; wp core update --allow-root; done
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20170723050601.E8FBF3EF4F@machine_name>
Date: Sun, 23 Jul 2017 05:06:01 +0000 (UTC)

/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found
```

Comment: Are you sure it runs on every folder? Also instead of changing the working directory via `cd`, consider using the `--path=""` parameter

Comment: Yes. Is the path parameter you mention path of WPCLI?

Comment: [Yes.](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/), path is part of standard WP-CLI. I'm not a fan of such one-liners, I placed basically the same things in a simple bash script, which will be executed by cron - much easier to debug

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Can you share how you've installed WP-CLI?

The `/bin/sh: 1: wp: not found` error implies the `wp` executable isn't found when cron is running. If you're using a bash alias to reference WP-CLI, or your bash profile to modify `$PATH`, then neither will be loaded automatically in the cron context.

Comment: Hi, I used this to install WP-CLI as part of my regular VPS environment creation script: `cd ~ && curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp`

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236725/whats-the-proper-way-to-setup-wp-cli-on-ubuntu-so-that-i-dont-have-to-use-the

Answer (score 1):

Understanding this answer requires preliminary knowledge in a system administration and Linux issue named "Environment variables". Acquiring this knowledge could be done with a didactic Linux book, course, or tutor. If one explanation was bad, seek another.

---

### The problem and the solution:

It seems to happen due to a **partial utilization** of the PATH environment variable, by cron.

When cron runs it has only the `/usr/bin` value of this variable, instead the whole set, common in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

What I did was to add the full location of WP-CLI to the commands (I also splitted the long one-liner command to two short commands):

From:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp plugin update --all --allow-root; done
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && wp core update --allow-root; done
```

To:

```
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && /usr/local/bin/wp plugin update --all --allow-root; done
0 0 * * * for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do cd "$dir" && /usr/local/bin/wp core update --allow-root; done
```

Note the `/usr/local/bin/` right before `wp`.

To test this works without waiting a whole day I changed the cron schedule from `0 0 * * *` (in the first minute, of the first hour, in each day of month, in each month, in each day of week), to this:

```
* * * * *
```

(in each minute, in each hour, in each day of month, in each month, in each day of week).

After about 2 minutes I checked one of my websites and saw everything was updated (besides themes, which updating them isn't included in the two commands I used).

Comment: upvoted, but why not to just write a shell script like kero sugested in the comments?

Comment: Running wp-cli as root introduces a nightmare's worth of security holes as essentially you are executing code from the user websites as root.  This is horribly dangerous and would result in your box being owned.  You *must* run wp-cli as the end user.  If you leave it as it is, it's only a matter of time before it's exploited.

Comment: Also worth noting that many versions of cron/crontab will allow you to change the PATH with a PATH line, thus removing the need for full paths.  With this length of script, I'd usually embed it in a shell script, if only to make error checking simpler.